Extending the speech recognition interval in the Modules.ASR module
tell me how in the Modules.ASR module you can extend the speech recognition interval, otherwise it happens that the person has not yet finished speaking and the recognition process has already ended, you can somehow avoid this.
I tried many different options, nothing helps, I did
  asr = VoxEngine.createASR({
        profile: profiletVoice,
        singleUtterance: false,
        interimResults: true

    })

The recognition interval becomes unpredictable, sometimes for a long time, sometimes quickly.
can anyone suggest a solutio
